# control page setting while printing

Tags: css, printing

I am trying to print a webpage . I used print.css separately.  but the printed page gets things like date,page number and page being printed...how do remove these things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a browser setting; the solution will vary by browser.

In Firefox, open **File -> Page Setup...**, select the **Margins & Header/Footer** tab, and select your settings.

In IE8, the settings are in the print menu under Page Setup.

Other browsers will have their own settings, though I imagine they are not much different.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. The CSS and HTML are not responsible for the extra headers when printing; it is the browser.